# Problem with jQuery slidein background

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add some slide in/out descriptions to images using jQuery as described [here](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/show/83-jquery-text-slide-up-slide-down-effect).  When I apply it to my site, the text (in the `<p>`) slides in as expected, but for some reason, the background of the text is shown under the picture.  I have played with z-order with no effect.  So far, I haven't been able to isolate this in an simple example, but I was hoping that this was one of those common problems...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".product-image").fadeIn("slow");  

    $(function(){  
        $('.productInfo').showFeatureText();    
    })

$.fn.showFeatureText = function() {
    return this.each(function(){    
    var box = $(this);
    var text = $('p',this);            

    box.hover(
        function(){
            text.slideDown("fast");
            text.css('z-index', '1000');    
        },
        function(){
            text.slideUp("fast");
        }
    );

  });
}

});
```

---

```
.product {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 12px;
    width: 215px;
}

    .product .productInfo {
        height: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;        

    }

        .product h3 {
            font-size: 1.75em;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0 0 0px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .product-image {
            background-color: #edece8;
            border: 1px #e6e3d8 solid;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 0 0px 0;
            padding: 6px;
            width: 200px;
            display:none;

        }

        .product p {
            margin: -75px 6px 6px 6px;
            display:none;
            background: #000000; url(/Images/feature_bg.png) repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
            height:65px;
            width:200px;
            z-index:1;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
```

Comment: can you post you html code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` is pointless without a `position`, so try setting `position:relative` on the picture and its containers and the `p` and it's containers. Also, be sure to set the `z-index` on all of these as well.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help.  Now, I can't see the text either.  Is there an implied z-order here?  Is it weird that the text comes up but its background goes behind?

Comment: Got it - I had to set position:relative on only the parent.  Setting it on the higher up containers cause me not to even get the events in jQuery for some reason.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi Adam I made an example that should work for you, I hope this helps you

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/gKytu/